# Test class error

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

i have to pass the test class but the error is not resolving iam not bale to find the  error  can you please help what i have to do to pass this test class

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Values for previous months can not be modified.: []

Thanks,
prince

Comment: Please provide code for better understanding. You must be violating a field validation. You can go through this post, It can help.
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25074/field-custom-validation-exception-during-unit-test

Comment: Can you share some of the code you are testing? It seems like you have a validation rule set up that triggers.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002540&language=en_US):

> **Description** Why am I getting a FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION when trying to deploy a changeset?
>
> **Resolution** This error occurs when there is a validation rule and one of the test methods is hitting exception caused by a validation
>   when creating/updating a test record.

In this case the validation rule, as the error suggests, is stopping the value of previous months from being modified.