# Regarding exception during test class creation for trigger

Tags: unit-test

> System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>
> First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You have selected an invalid
>   "Type" option for a MACD record.: [Type]

I am receiving this error and any1 please help me out what would be the reason

Comment: looks like you have selected wrong `Type` for `MACD record`. Open Type field check you validation rule. Based on that assigned the value to Type field

Comment: The reason is you are trying to insert a record where it's not a valid record based on a validation rule in your environment. Check the validation rule condition and initialize the record so that it's a valid one and then insert

Comment: You have selected an invalid "Type" option for a MACD record.this validation error it s not present

Comment: Can you tell us what type of object are you creating? We're all assuming that MACD is a custom object type with a custom field called "Type". Is that correct? Does it have any validation rules? I would try to replicate this by tring to create one interactively and see if you get the same error again

Answer (score 0):

This typically occurs when you have some custom validation rules on your object.

This is what [Salesforce said about this error and possible solution](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002540&language=en_US):

> This error occurs when there is a validation rule and one of the test
>   methods is hitting exception caused by a validation when
>   creating/updating a test record.
>
> The solution is to modify the record(s) in the DML operation such that
>   they comply with the validation rule. The validation rule is there for
>   a reason, so it should be obeyed. Turning off the validation rule
>   temporarily isn't advisable, as it means the test method isn't
>   reflective of the correct production schema, and hence neither is your
>   Apex code.

So in general you will have to check your data that hitting this exception against your validation rules.

This topic could be helpful as well: [FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION during Unit Test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25074/field-custom-validation-exception-during-unit-test)